# firefox extension cross domain iframe https

Tags: firefox, iframe, cross-domain, firefox-addon-sdk

Firefox extension devs: When following this example: [cross domain content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts#Cross-domain_iframes) for accessing say wikipedia org in an iframe hosted on localhost, it works, but when accessing an https url it doesnt. Code that works:

```
$(function(){
      $('iframe').each(function() {
      try{
          console.log(this.contentWindow.location.href);          
      } catch(e){
       console.log(e.message);
      }

    });
});
```

package.json:

```
 "permissions": {
  "cross-domain-content": ["http://en.m.wikipedia.org/"]
  },
```

but then switch the iframe in the localhost html file from wikipedia to something like:

```
 <iframe src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps/ms?ll=19.086522,72.89492&amp;spn=0.001328,0.002642&amp;t=m&amp;z=19&amp;iwloc=0004da9d79b2aac93619b&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=208618496919443620091.0004da9d6f3c4668ebdfa&output=embed"></iframe>
```

and edit permissions with this:

```
 "permissions": {
   "cross-domain-content": ["https://maps.google.co.in/maps/ms?ll=19.086522,72.89492&amp;spn=0.001328,0.002642&amp;t=m&amp;z=19&amp;iwloc=0004da9d79b2aac93619b&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=208618496919443620091.0004da9d6f3c4668ebdfa&output=embed", "https://maps.google.co.in/","https://maps.google.co.in/maps/ms"]
```

},

and it gets: "Permission denied to access property 'href'"

Comment: You just need to add the domain to the list.  Have you tried that?

`"cross-domain-content": ["https://maps.google.co.in"]`